# Sums of different lists using recursion

Tags: scala, list, recursion, functional-programming, int

I am doing CodeWars challenges again and today I have a problem with this one:

Let us consider this example (array written in general format):

```
ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Its following parts:

```
ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
ls = [1, 3, 6, 10]
ls = [3, 6, 10]
ls = [6, 10]
ls = [10]
ls = []
```

The corresponding sums are (put together in a list): [20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]

The function parts_sums (or its variants in other languages) will take as parameter a list ls and return a list of the sums of its parts as defined above.

```
object SumsOfParts {

  def partsSums(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {

    var x: List[Int] = List()
    if (l.isEmpty)
      x
    else {
      x :+ l.sum
      partsSums(l.tail)
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the test samples:

> partsSums(List(0, 1, 3, 6, 10)) should return List(20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0)
>   Test Failed
>
> tail of empty list
>   Stack Trace
>   Completed in 4ms
>   partsSums(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) should return List(21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 0)
>   Test Failed
>
> tail of empty list
>   Stack Trace
>   partsSums(List(744125, 935, 407, 454, 430, 90, 144, 6710213, 889, 810, 2579358)) should return List(10037855, 9293730, 9292795, 9292388, 9291934, 9291504, 9291414, 9291270, 2581057, 2580168, 2579358, 0)
>   Test Failed
>
> tail of empty list
>   Stack Trace
>   Completed in 1ms
>   partsSums(List(30350, 76431, 156228, 78043, 98977, 80169, 32457, 182875, 162323, 17508, 57971, 171907)) should return List(1145239, 1114889, 1038458, 882230, 804187, 705210, 625041, 592584, 409709, 247386, 229878, 171907, 0)
>   Test Failed

Comment: 1) Please fix the indentation: what happened to it? 2) `ls.scanRight(0)(_ + _)`.

Comment: Maybe `ls.tails.map(_.sum)` ? That solution wouldn't be the most performant though.

Comment: Sorry for the indentation, but the compiler has mistaken the list at the beggining of the question as code, hence the output. I fixed some bits should be better now.

Comment: You should really do some simple debugging before running to SO. Each iteration creates a new and empty `x` which is why it always returns an empty `List`.

Comment: Why do you want recursion? Does CodeWars care if it's recursive?

Comment: Bo it does not,but that was the first idea which came into my mind.

Comment: Give your ideas if you have, that was the first solution I thought of though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `var` in your recursive functions to pass state. You could fix your method like that:

```
def partsSums(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (l.isEmpty)
      Nil //to finish recursion return empty list
    else {
      l.sum :: partsSums(l.tail) //prepend newly calculated sum to list returned by recursive call
    }
}
```

But this solution is naive since it recalculates sum on every iteration. We could make it better taking the previous sum from the head of the result and calculating the new sum by just adding it to the head of the list. I also use another list called `acc` to accumulate results, because this way I can make `partsSums2` tail-recursive:

```
def partsSums2(l: List[Int], acc: List[Int] = List(0)): List[Int] = {
    if(l.isEmpty) {
      acc //at the end of recursion we return acc, which holds result
    } else {
      //acc.head is previos sum and l.head is value I want to add
      partsSums2(l.tail, (l.head + acc.head) :: acc)
    }
}
```

In order to make it work we also need to reverse list before passing to method:

```
SumsOfParts.partsSums2(List(0, 1, 3, 6, 10).reverse)
```

We need to reverse the list because the implementation of the immutable list in Scala is very affective on prepend operations (*O(1)*), but not on append operations (*O(n)*).

Finally you could just use `scanRight`:

```
def partsSums3(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = l.scanRight(0)(_ + _)
```

Comment: You can make `partsSums2` slightly cleaner if you set the default value for `acc` to `List(0)`. That way, `head` should always exist so you don't need the `headOption`. You can use `cats.NonEmptyList` to enforce that at compile time.

Comment: @Ethan Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

As @Andrey commented `scanLeft` solves this problem, but here is a recursive solution:

```scala
  def partsSums(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (l.isEmpty) {
      Nil
    } else {

      def go(list: List[Int], acc: List[Int], currentSum: Int): List[Int] =

        list match {
          case Nil => (0 :: acc).reverse
          case x :: xs =>
            go(xs, currentSum :: acc, currentSum - x)
        }

      go(l, Nil, l.sum)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(partsSums(List(0, 1, 3, 6, 10)))
    // List(20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0)
    println(partsSums(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))
    // List(21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 0)
    println(partsSums(List(744125, 935, 407, 454, 430, 90, 144, 6710213, 889, 810, 2579358)))
    // List(10037855, 9293730, 9292795, 9292388, 9291934, 9291504, 9291414, 9291270, 2581057, 2580168, 2579358, 0)
    println(partsSums(List(30350, 76431, 156228, 78043, 98977, 80169, 32457, 182875, 162323, 17508, 57971, 171907)))
   // List(1145239, 1114889, 1038458, 882230, 804187, 705210, 625041, 592584, 409709, 247386, 229878, 171907, 0)
  }
```